# MySQL 8 disk usage always grow

Tags: mysql, logging

MySQL's disk space usage increases as time goes on, but drops all at once when I restart MySQL. After much investigation I think I have found the cause of the problem, it seems that MySQL is writing to a file even though it is marked as deleted.
Do you know how I can avoid this kind of problem?

MySQL version : 8.0.21
OS: CentOS 8

Command used for:
lsof -u mysql | grep REG | grep /home/mysql/log/query.log

Return:
mysqld  1387561 mysql   36w      REG              253,0 8301798945  17011295 /home/mysql/log/query.log-20230110 (deleted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a **feature of Unix**.

- The shell command `rm` (and the C function `unlink()`) deletes a file from the directory it is in.  But it does not remove it from disk until the file is closed.
- `/tmp/` is cleared after any reboot.
- Some products deliberately open a file for writing and then immediately `unlink()` it.  Then they write (and read) it.  This action, together with the items above provides a way to create a temp file that is guaranteed to go away even if things crash.
- `mv` renames a file by adding a link to it, then unlinking the original file.  (There are more details.)
- MySQL's `FLUSH LOGS` "closes" all logs and reopens them.  So, if `mv` or `rm` was done in the meanwhile, MySQL will now actually be writing the correctly *named* file.

MySQL has several log files.  In some installations, some of them are automatically 'rotated' by utilities driven by `cron`.  This rotation may perform a `mv` to give it a new name or simply `rm` it.  Either way, `mysqld` is oblivious to it since it still has the file open.

**binlog**

The binary log is where MySQL writes for replication and/or for backup.  After a set amount of space (default: 100MB), it will close the file and open a new file with a higher sequence number.

Meanwhile, it may also "expire" old binlog file(s) based on another turnable.
That is, some old file(s) will be deleted.

I like to set the expiration to 7 days.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%expire_logs%';` to see what your system is doing.

If you are seeing a drop of about 100MB, I would check the binlogs.

**general log**

The "general log" fills up disk rapidly because it records every query performed.  There is no auto-rotate or auto-purge.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%general%';`

Are you asking out of curiosity?  Or is disk space a problem?

Comment: Thanks for these explanations on how Linux works with deleted files. I will try to find a solution to make a log rotate on the querylog file

Comment: @rhiezcnl - There are different techniques, based on whether you want to (1) immediately toss (rm+flush) (2) keep just one backup (rm,mv,flush) or (3) keep lots of backups (mv,flush)